# CSS Submenu Disappearing too quickly

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I have edited the CSS on my menu on this site:

So it would display completely across at the font size I want (previously it was turning into a two layer menu). However, now for some reason the submenu under "Show Your Support" is very difficult to click on. When you hover and try to move your mouse down to an option it disappears half the time before you can click on anything.

I have played around with the code in Chrome (inspect element) and I can't seem to find out what is wrong. Can someone assist me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: This is usually caused by a gap between the menu and sub menu which, if you traverse too slowly, the submenu has already hidden.  You need to remove the gap so that the two elements butt up against each other - leaving nowhere for the mouse pointer to be "in the gap".  Try putting a temporary border around the elements to see the gap - and get an idea what to change to remove it.

Comment: Thank you! It was the gap and I could not fix it for some reason. I erased all of my code and started over and somehow it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gap between the menu and where the sub-menu appears. See Image below: [image: Gap]

When you hover away from the menu item and the mouse is on its way to the sub-menu, the mouse ceases to be on 'hover' (while crossing over the gap) - making the sub-menu disappear.

If you can eliminate the gap (i.e. place where the sub-menu is positioned higher up the page), the 'hover' state will remain on mouse-move and the sub-menu will stay 'shown' for clicking.

Does that help?

PS
posted as an answer (instead of comment) so I could include the image in my explanation.

Comment: I just added a comment, 'cus I'm lazy.  You took the time to include an image...  so the points are all yours...  enjoy spending them :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your show your support tag, inside add this style

```
style="padding-bottom:10px;"
```

So that I am able to operate now without any hover before on click issue. try and let me know. I tried in IE.