# Unordered List Dropdown Submenu - Stay Activated When Clicked

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm working on the navbar for a site and for the menu it has an unordered list with submenus that are actived when the menu item is hovered over, but when you remove your mouse from the menu item to attempt to click on a submenu item the submenu dissapears. Is there a way with CSS/HTML to hover over it, then have the user click on it to keep it activated? If that's not possible, is it possible to change it to stay activated on a click without the preview on the hover?

HTML:

```
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="header">

             <div class="topbar">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                         <li class="smallsocial">&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li>
                               <li class="smallsocial"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/prayingpelicanmissions" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smallsocial">
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/+PrayingpelicanmissionsOrg" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Google Plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="smallsocial">
                                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/petepelican?sub_confirmation=1" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Youtube">
                                    <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="smallsocial">
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/PrayingPelican" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="smallsocial">
                                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/prayingpelicanmissions/" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Instagram">
                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                </a></li><li>&nbsp;</li>

                            <li class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-dark"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></button></li>
                              <li class="pull-right"><button class="btn btn-dark"><a href="https://www.prayingpelicanmissions.org/account/">LOGIN</a></button></li>
                        </ul>



             </div>
                    <!-- End Social Links -->

             <div class="navbar mega-menu" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="menu-container">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    <!-- Navbar Brand -->
                        <div class="navbar-brand">
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <img class="default-logo" src="assets/img/whitelogo.png" alt="Logo">
                                <img class="shrink-logo" src="assets/img/blacklogo.png" alt="Logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <!-- ENd Navbar Brand -->

                    <!-- Header Inner Right -->

                    <!-- End Header Inner Right -->
                    </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <div class="menu-container">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <!-- Home -->
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pull-right dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    About Us
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="index.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Trip Media</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Trip Journals</a></li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li> <a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            <!-- End Home -->

                            <!-- Shortcodes -->
                                <li class="dropdown mega-menu-fullwidth">

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pull-right dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Locations
                                    </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                        <div class="mega-menu-content disable-icons">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <div class="row equal-height">
                                                    <div class="col-md-3 equal-height-in">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                                                            <li><h3>United States</h3></li>

                                                            <!-- Typography -->
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_general.html"><i></i> Tucson, AZ</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_headings.html"><i></i>San Francisco, CA</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_dividers.html"><i></i> Miami, FL</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_blockquote.html"><i></i> Chicago, IL</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_boxshadows.html"><i></i> Boston, MA</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_testimonials.html"><i></i>Minneapolis, MN</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_tagline_boxes.html"><i></i> Pittsburg, PA</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_grid.html"><i></i> Providence, RI</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_grid.html"><i></i> Memphis, TN</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_typo_grid.html"><i></i>US Reservations</a></li>
                                                            <!-- End Typography -->
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3 equal-height-in">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                                                            <li><h3>CENTRAL AMERICA</h3></li>

                                                            <!-- Buttons -->
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_general.html"><i></i>Belize</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_brands.html"><i></i>Costa Rica</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Guatemala</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Mexico</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Nicaragua</a></li>
                                                            <!-- End Buttons -->


                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-3 equal-height-in">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                                                            <li><h3>CARIBBEAN</h3></li>

                                                            <!-- Buttons -->
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_general.html"><i></i>Bahamas</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_brands.html"><i></i>Cuba</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Dominican Republic</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Haiti</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Jamaica</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>Puerto Rico</a></li>
                                                            <!-- End Buttons -->


                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md-3 equal-height-in">
                                                        <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                                                            <li><h3>AFRICA/EUROPE</h3></li>

                                                            <!-- Buttons -->
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_general.html"><i></i>Italy</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_brands.html"><i></i>Ghana</a></li>
                                                            <li class="location"><a href="shortcode_btn_effects.html"><i></i>South Africa</a></li>

                                                            <!-- End Buttons -->


                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Shortcodes -->

                            <!-- Demo Pages -->
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="http://www.prayingpelicanmissions.org/journals">
                                    Trip Journals
                                </a>
                            </li>
                           <li class=".button12">
                                <a href="http://www.prayingpelicanmissions.org/mission-trip-registration">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">REGISTER FOR A TRIP</button>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <div class="header-inner-right">


                            <li class="menu-icons">
                                <i class="menu-icons-style search search-close search-btn fa fa-search"></i>
                                <div class="search-open">
                                    <input type="text" class="animated fadeIn form-control" placeholder="Start searching ...">
                                </div>
                            <!-- End Demo Pages -->
                        </ul>

                <!--/navbar-collapse-->
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
        </div>


        </div>  <!-- End Navbar -->
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far

Comment: Please review [ask]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a small gap between the menu and submenu. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012212/css-submenu-disappearing-too-quickly).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally some code would help, but sounds like a nested dropdown would be more accurate, also I assume you are using Bootstrap 3?

Check this example [Multi level dropdown menu BS3](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)